# Edit an object in backbone

Tags: object, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am new to using backbone in parse.com environment. I simply want to edit the second model object but I dont know how to open the edit box for the second object.

The current working model is the following, I have added "dblclick label.todo-job" : "edit1" and can get it started by double clicking it.

```
events: {
      "click .toggle"              : "toggleDone",
      "dblclick label.todo-content" : "edit",
      "dblclick label.todo-job" : "edit1",
      "click .todo-destroy"   : "clear",
      "keypress .edit"      : "updateOnEnter",
      "blur .edit"          : "close"
    },
```

The following is the function to allow editing my object.

```
edit1: function() {
  $(this.el).addClass("editing");
  this.input.focus();
},
```

However, it only opens this object "label.todo-content" to edit while I want to edit "label.todo-job". How can I change the focus to the new object.

Thats the whole code if you need.

```
  // The DOM element for a todo item...
  var TodoView = Parse.View.extend({

    //... is a list tag.
    tagName:  "li",

    // Cache the template function for a single item.
    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    // The DOM events specific to an item.
    events: {
      "click .toggle"              : "toggleDone",
       "dblclick label.todo-content" : "edit",
      "dblclick label.todo-job" : "edit1",
      "dblclick label.todo-phone" : "edit2",
      "dblclick label.todo-email" : "edit3",
      "dblclick label.todo-website" : "edit4",
      "dblclick label.todo-address" : "edit5", 
      "click .todo-destroy"   : "clear",
      "keypress .edit"      : "updateOnEnter",
      "blur .edit"          : "close"
    },

    // The TodoView listens for changes to its model, re-rendering. Since there's
    // a one-to-one correspondence between a Todo and a TodoView in this
    // app, we set a direct reference on the model for convenience.
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close', 'remove');
      this.model.bind('change', this.render);
      this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove);
    },

    // Re-render the contents of the todo item.
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      this.input = this.$('.edit');
      return this;
    },

    // Toggle the `"done"` state of the model.
    toggleDone: function() {
      this.model.toggle();
    },

    // Switch this view into `"editing"` mode, displaying the input field.
    edit: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },
        edit1: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },
        edit2: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },
        edit3: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },
        edit4: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },
        edit5: function() {
      $(this.el).addClass("editing");
      this.input.focus();
    },

    // Close the `"editing"` mode, saving changes to the todo.
    close: function() {
      this.model.save({content: this.input.val()});
      $(this.el).removeClass("editing");
    },

    // If you hit `enter`, we're through editing the item.
    updateOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) this.close();
    },

    // Remove the item, destroy the model.
    clear: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    }

  });
```

Below is the objects added in the HTML.

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
      <li class="<%= done ? 'completed' : '' %>">
  <div class="view">
    <li><label class="todo-content"><%= _.escape(content) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-job"><%= _.escape(job) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-phone"><%= _.escape(phone) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-email"><%= _.escape(email) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-website"><%= _.escape(web) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-address"><%= _.escape(address) %></label></li>
    <li><label class="todo-postcode"><%= _.escape(postcode) %></label></li>
    <button class="todo-destroy"></button>
  </div>
  <input class="edit" value="<%= _.escape(content) %>">
  <input class="edit" value="<%= _.escape(content) %>"> /*I need to edit this instead of the object above this*/
      </li>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An event triggers on the deepest possible element.which means `this` of Event handler function is not element you select for event listener but element where the actual event occurs.
I don't know about `parse.com` though,I assume that `label.todo-content` is inside of `label.todo-job`. And that makes Event handler's callback `this` into `label.todo-content`.

So If you explicitly select element to focus,It should work.
FYI, Backbone View has `$`(http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) and `$el` (http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) parameters to use jQuery methods for elements in side of the View.Since global `$` is able to edit any elements over each controller's View area, using `this.$` is always recommended.

```
edit1: function() {
  this.$el.addClass("editing");
  this.$("label.todo-job").focus();
},
```

**EDITED**
I got what you asked about.
I do not know how you wrote your HTML code but the code you provided is pointing first `input` if your input tags have class name,

```
edit1: function() {
  this.$el.addClass("editing");
  this.$(".yourClassNameForInput").focus();
},
```

or if you do know have class/id name,You can also do this.

```
edit1: function() {
  this.$el.addClass("editing");
  this.$("input").eq(0).focus();
},
....
edit5: function() {
  this.$el.addClass("editing");
  this.$("label.todo-job").eq(4).focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suish but this code still this brings on the same element for edit ie todo-content.  "label.todo-job" is not inside "label.todo-job" but at the same level as "label.todo-content" if I understand correctly what you mean.

Comment: Could you please provide more codes and exactly what you want to achieve? jsfiddle is the best if you could.

Comment: just added my whole code to the bottom of the question. The code allows to edit first item while I want to edit all of them by double click. Currently double click on any items only brings up the first element to edit.

Comment: Suish, it doesnt not actually point to first object, I possibly dont understand when using class and id. But when I change the first and second list item below still only the todo-content comes up for editing. I added below the question my HTML code.

Comment: Suish,  I got the issue now, as you can see in my HTML code I have added an input object and it is picked up when passing an editing class in my backbone template. Now I need to tell the code to pick up the second input object rather than the first one.